# Behavior of onBackPressed with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

I want to override a custom behavior for a fragment.

I have three different fragment in my Activity. Two of them are a toolbar and a banner, so I don't want to go back on these two. But In the other fragment I want to override a custom behavior when back button is pressed.

And back button is not the Android back button, is other button I have created on the first fragment: the toolbar, when the user clicks on my back button, the fragments launch a interface's method. Just like this:

```
mListener.onToolbarInteraction(v);
```

I have tried to override the onBackPressed() Android's method and wrote my code. Also, I have set a Tag on the fragment I want the indicated behavior, but not in others two.

This is the XML of activity:

**.XML :**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fm_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.iurban.restaurant.Fragments.MainFragment"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/alphaBlack"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fm_toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fm_banner"
    class="com.iurban.restaurant.Fragments.MainFragment"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fm_banner"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    class="com.iurban.restaurant.Fragments.MainFragment"/>
```

This is methods to initiate the fragments:

**Initiate Method :**

```
private void startMenu(short idFather){
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment(getApplicationContext(), usedLang.getId(), idFather);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fl_container, mainFragment)
            .addToBackStack(CustomConstants.LEVEL)
            .commit();
}

private void startToolbar(){
    ToolbarFragment toolbarFragment = new ToolbarFragment(usedLang);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fm_toolbar,toolbarFragment)
            .show(fmToolbar)
            .commit();

}

private void startBanner(){
    BannerDAO bannerDAO = new BannerDAO(getApplicationContext());
    Banner banner = bannerDAO.obtainingUniqueBanner();

    if(banner != null && banner.getActive() == 1){
        BannerFragment bannerFragment = new BannerFragment(banner, getApplicationContext(), (byte)usedLang.getId());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fm_banner,bannerFragment)
                .show(fmBanner)
                .commit();
    }else{
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .hide(fmBanner)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

this is the on back pressed overrided:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count > 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

The behavior I expected is a level list navigation. In the menu fragment you have a recyclerview and when you click/tap in a element then you "go to the next level" and it's showed a list of children of the element you clicked. So when you press back, I expected the app goes back to the last list, but the result I have (going to the third level menu) is:

- you tap once, nothing happens.
- You tap another time and go back 1 level.
- From here nothing happens when you tap.

I just to realize (printing logs) that the backstack is uptated, but the fragment is not updated.

I wrote this method to print the IDs of the back stack:

```
private void printStack(){
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    Log.e("BACKSTACK","-----------------------------------------------");
    for(int  i = 0; i < count; i++){
        Log.e("BACKSTACK",String.valueOf(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getId()));
    }
}
```

When I tap the back button (on the third level of menu) the method I have done to print logs print this:

- E/BACKSTACK: 0
- E/BACKSTACK: 1
- E/BACKSTACK: 2

And after super.onBackPressed(); prints this:

- E/BACKSTACK: 0
- E/BACKSTACK: 1

But the fragment is not updated, it still showing the same level.

Comment: try putting if(count == 1)

Comment: Your explanation of flow is not clear.

Comment: @Ashish it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this ....

Just add `.addToBackStack(null)` method when you need back behavior, when you starting your fragment like below.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_parent_id, new YourFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And don't `.addToBackStack(null)` method when you don't needed back behavior.

Note:- you don't have to do anything inside your `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: Hi Sushil Kumar I tried this, if you can see I have set .addToBackStack(CustomConstants.LEVEL); at the fragment I want the back property. Anyway I tried with null too but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have only one activity?. When you press back button it will show you nothing? .

Comment: I have two Activities. When apps starts it shows other activity when I download data, afther that the apps show the current activity and build the fragments

Comment: So, you want to go back to your previous activity on Back presss?

Comment: No, this is because I am overriding the onBackPressed method, when the back stack count is 1 i don't want to go back more.

Comment: Just check your import fragment file tell me ? Your is same like this `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` ?

Comment: Yes the import I have is import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;